# Why is LSHW Only listing one of my two HDDs?

Tags: hardware, lvm

I have a 120GB HDD and a 1TB HDD in the system.  I installed Ubuntu Server using LVM on the 120GB.  After installation I added the 1TB to the existing volume group and added 10GB to /home as a test.

My understanding is that lshw is supposed to list hardware.  What's the difference here?

```
 mark@server:~$ sudo lshw -short -c disk
 H/W path           Device      Class          Description
 =========================================================
/0/100/1f.2/0      /dev/sda    disk           120GB ST3120026AS
/0/100/1f.2/1      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+-RW GH50N
/0/1/0.0.0         /dev/sdc    disk           SCSI Disk
/0/1/0.0.1         /dev/sdd    disk           SCSI Disk
/0/1/0.0.2         /dev/sde    disk           SCSI Disk
/0/1/0.0.3         /dev/sdf    disk           SCSI Disk
```

The 1TB only shows up as a volume, not as a disk.

```
 mark@server:~$ sudo lshw -short
 ....
 /0/100/1f.2/0      /dev/sda    disk           120GB ST3120026AS
 /0/100/1f.2/0/1    /dev/sda1   volume         476MiB Linux filesystem partition
 /0/100/1f.2/0/2    /dev/sda2   volume         111GiB Linux LVM Physical Volume partition
 /0/100/1f.2/1      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+-RW GH50N
 /0/100/1f.2/0.0.0  /dev/sdb    volume         931GiB WDC WD1001FALS-0
```

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

That would be a bug, lshw categorized it incorrectly, please create a lp issue and link the bug to this post. **[UPDATE]** you could always use **lsscsi** which is specifically designed for this task and has been around for a long long time.